# gcp create_notification_channel creates a duplicate channel

Tags: google-cloud-platform

GCP Python client method to Create Monitoring Notification channel is not idempotent.
Duplicate Channels under same Project are getting created.

Is there a way to avoid duplication?

[create_notification_channel](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/monitoring/latest/google.cloud.monitoring_v3.services.notification_channel_service.NotificationChannelServiceClient#google_cloud_monitoring_v3_services_notification_channel_service_NotificationChannelServiceClient_create_notification_channel)

Comment: Do you have the possibilty to use a tool like `Terraform` instead of do that with the `Python` client ?

Comment: No, Use case is to deploy the Code via Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the documentation it's not possible to handle duplicates directly but you can solve your issue with the following actions :

- List the existing notification channels in `GCP` via the `list_notification_channels`
- Loop on the actual notifications channels (maybe configured in your code), if the element exist in `GCP` (check from the list retrieved previously), update it via `update_notification_channel` function, otherwise create it with `create_notification_channel` function.

Comment: Thanks Mazium, Do you think A bug/feature request should be put with GCP?